# Deefine a Sequence of Random Variables in Maple?

Tags: probability, maple

I want to use the Statistics package that enables to do symbolic calculations with random variables to define a sequence of random variables.

This code does not work:

```
restart;
with(Statistics):
X:=RandomVariable(DiscreteUniform(1,26));
seq(X(i),i=0..1000);
```

because it displays:

```
> Mean(X(5));
> 
                                                        _R(5)
```

Instead of 27/2. 
Does somebody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make **X** a Vector, like this:

```
X:= Vector(1000, ()-> Statistics:-RandomVariable(DiscreteUniform(1,26))):
```

Then you can give commands like

```
Statistics:-Mean(X(5));
```

and you'll get your expected output.

If you insist on indexing starting at 0, it's a tiny bit more complicated. Change the defining command to

```
X:= Array(0..1000, ()-> Statistics:-RandomVariable(DiscreteUniform(1,26))):
```

And you'll need to do the indexing with square brackets: **X[0]**, **X[5]**, etc,

Comment: Thank you a lot. :) Why did my approach fail?

Comment: You defined **X** as a single random variable. As such, it can't be indexed. I made **X** a container object which contains 1000 random variables.